# Django NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented

Tags: django, orm, psql

I want to count the total number of specific values in the `structure` field.

```
Fund.objects.all().exclude(structure__isnull=True).extra(select={'Structure': 'structure'}).values('Structure').annotate(total=Count('structure')).order_by('-total')
```

But before I do, I want to apply `distinct()` function so that only the objects with distinct `id` will be used for the query. So i tried something like this:

```
object_list = Fund.objects.all().distinct('id')
object_list.exclude(structure__isnull=True).extra(select={'Structure': 'structure'}).values('Structure').annotate(total=Count('structure'))
```

But I get the error:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

How can I achieve this?

In Psql:

```
CREATE VIEW distinct_funds as select distinct id, structure from Fund;

SELECT count(structure), structure from distinct_funds GROUP BY structure;
```